# How to detect which Grails test phases (unit / integration) will be executed at runtime?

Tags: unit-testing, grails, functional-testing, spock

I'm [writing a SpockConfig.groovy file](http://wordpress.transentia.com.au/wordpress/2014/04/23/using-spock-configuration-in-grails/) in order to include/exclude certain Spock test methods (feature methods) from running.

My goal is to run certain functional tests as long as no unit or integration tests are going to be run ([workaround due to a bug in Grails](https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-11355)).

**My main question:**
Is there a way to detect, at runtime (hopefully in SpockConfig.groovy) if unit/integration tests are planned to be executed? (i.e., if "grails test-app unit: functional" was used vs. "grails test-app functional:")

Thanks :)

Comment: Have you seen the Spock IgnoreIf extension?

Comment: Yes, but its functionality is not sufficient: it cannot run only a functional tests; it can only ignore a few or run everything on top of all others. It's like I want left-outer or right-outer, not the intersection at all.  Additionally, it doesn't help me run functional tests only if unit/integration are not run. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: It can ignore whatever you tell it to ignore. If you manage to set a system property when your integration tests are run then you can annotate other Spock tests with IgnoreIf (that examines this system property). The trick is how to set this system property by the Grails builds...

Comment: I don't want to annotate every single test. I have 600 tests total: 100 unit tests and 500 functional tests and want 20 of the 600 to run alone in certain cases, and 580 to run under other cases. I already have this working: I annotated the 20 using my own annotation which gets its rules via SpockConfig.groovy (see the link in my post for instructions). To achieve all this I have to run two commands, "grails test-app -DspecialProp=true functional:" to run the 20, and "grails test-app unit: functional:" to run the 580. If my question is answered then I won't need "specialProp" at all. Thx :)

Comment: Ok. I suggest you include your last comment in the question itself, because it makes the problem more clear.